# Why my OnLongClickListener not workiong

Tags: android

subList is a custom view adapter the code is below. Why its not working?

Code:

```
TimeTableSubjectAdapter subList = new TimeTableSubjectAdapter(this,words);

ListView drawList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.SubjectsDragList);

drawList.setAdapter(subList);
drawList.setClickable(true);
drawList.setLongClickable(true);
drawList.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        Log.e("TextView:","Picked up");
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data,shadowBuilder,view,0);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here... Is there an error being thrown? ... Could be an error in your xml, or your custom class.

Comment: Do you need to handle long click on item, not list view in general, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle clicks on items, not `ListView` in general

```
    drawList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have one more question. Please Help me    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304069/error-while-working-with-getlocalstate-method-on-array-objects

Comment: @AkhilP Nobody will help you because you are not follow site rules.